# Lehmann Test for prime numbers

Tags: cryptography

I learn cryptography at my university, and I need to make an application for testing numbers as prime numbers.

I must to do it using **Lehmann Test**, but I don't know anything about it. Please, describe me the algorithm or give me an example (Java, C#, C++, etc). Thank you for helping.

Comment: http://www.willwork.org/ics623/Week9.html

Comment: No, sorry. This is a programming Q & A site, not an undergraduate homework completion service.

Comment: You mean "Lukas-Lehmer" test, I guess? Why not just start with Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test?

Comment: Algorithm description: http://en.algoritmy.net/article/48610/Lehmann-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call PP your Potential Prime.

- (1) Choose a random number **a** less than PP.
- (2) Calculate a^(p-1)/2 mod PP.
- (3) If a^(PP-1)/2 /= 1 or -1 (mod PP), then PP is not prime.
- (4) If a^(PP-1)/2 = 1 or -1 (mod PP), then the probability that PP is not prime is less  than 50%.

Comment: So how to use the last formula 1 - 1 / 2^k ? I need to find the overall probability that a number is or is not prime. Please help.